# When should I ask for different work hours during the hiring process?

Tags: work-life-balance, work-time, hours

I am a student and I am looking for my first programming job (where I live -not USA- people work and study at the same time). In general people work from 9 a.m to 6 p.m (total: 9 hours, this includes one hour for lunch). University classes start at 5 p.m so I would like to work from 8 a.m to 4 p.m (and have only 45 minutes for lunch, total: 8 hours).

When should I ask for this? During the first interview? When they make an offer?

How can I let them know that it does not matter if I get paid less because I'd be working 8 hours instead of 9?

Comment: FYI, Usually the lunch hour doesn't count towards worked hours

Answer (score 9):

If you have set obligations to meet at certain times, then you need to let them know in the initial interview. You normally don't get to dictate your hours in your first job. But many companies make exceptions for students.

Comment: Many who hire students will explicitly ask you for your class schedule so they know what to expect.  This is not an unusual situation at all.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how important work hours are for you.

In you case they are important because else you'd miss uni. So tell him by the end of the first interview, after giving a good impression and that you are a real value to the company.

If different working hours are important to you, but it's more important that you get the job, I'd say wait for the second interview but talk about it at the beginning. Maybe even right before the money talk.

Comment: Good point about the different times. Essentially it depends on whether the times are negotiable for you. If they are not, you should bring it up as early as possible.